# How can a linter catch copy by reference in python?

Tags: python, lint

After a major overhaul of code (changing data structure, algorithm, and refactoring) a very sneaky bug creeped in.

```py
    self.thrown = board[c.THROWN]
```

Looking very benign, and I didn't give it a split second of thought when I wrote this line. However `board` happens to be a numpy 2D array and accessing it by a single index returns a *reference* to a list rather than a copy. This caused global state modification. Tracking this down was very tiresome as all tests (unit & integration) passed with flying colors. Solution was trivial, just create a local version with `board.copy()`. However my question is about preventing this bug in the first place, or at least limiting the amount of debugging time.

What could have alerted me that I'm about to do something-possibly unintentional? What kind of linter / code analysis could've caught this?

Comment: "However board happens to be a numpy array (a list of lists)" - NumPy arrays and lists of lists are completely different things with very different behavior. You should probably go read up on the differences.

Comment: I don't think getting a reference causes global state modification - I assume you changed `self.thrown` later? I don't see how a linter "fixes" this because its perfectly reasonable to get a reference to a row and then modify it somewhere else. If one had a "test first" methodology, a "modify self.thrown doesn't affect board" test could have been written as soon as a modification to self.thrown was made.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - In this case, a list of list would have behaved similarly. User would get a reference to the inner list, not a copy, and any modification would affect both. But I agree that numpy/pandas etc... frequently behave unexpectedly.

Comment: Just meant to indicate that it wasn't a single-dimension array. And yes, I modified `self.thrown` later and the input param `board` was reused by the calling function for another purpose.

Not asking for a linter to fix anything - just alert. There are cases where it would be intentional but I'm curious if the unintentional case can be warned about